# Remove mongo specific nested documents in array for each document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
        "_id" : 123,
        "a" : [
                {
                        "b" : 1,
                        "bb" : 2
                },
                {
                        "c" : 2,
                        "cc" : 3
                }
        ],
        "ab" : [
                {
                        "d" : 4,
                        "dd" : 5
                },
                {
                        "e" : 5,
                        "ee" : 6
                }
        ]
}
```

Need to remove mongo specific nested document in array for each document

Output should be like: based on inputs _id:123,ab.d=4

```
{
        "_id" : 123,
        "a" : [
                {
                        "b" : 1,
                        "bb" : 2
                },
                {
                        "c" : 2,
                        "cc" : 3
                }
        ],
        "ab" : [
                {
                        "e" : 5,
                        "ee" : 6
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Use `$elemMatch` projection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking for an update with $pull operator (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

In your case:

```
db.mycollection.update({"_id":123}, {$pull: {"ab":{"d":4}}})
```